# Price higher that I have set

Tags: commerce

I set the price of a drupal commerce product in 17 euros with "Include tax in this price" of VAT 10%. But I don't understand why when I view the display product I saw 21,39 euros.

I've looked at the "Manage display" of this product type. The Price field is formatted as "Formatted amount" and chosen "Display the calculated sell price for the current user.". If I change the format to the other option "Display the original price as loaded." when I see the display product node appears the price as 17 euros.

I don't understand where it's changing the price and how can I can configure.

Where, in the configuration, can I avoid this price change ?

Answer (score 0):

This just means you have some product pricing rule or promotion enabled on the site that raises the price by that amount. It's unrelated to your tax setting. This is why you only see the high price when you use a display formatter that calculates the price prior to display.

There's no way for anyone to diagnose this for you without access to your site. You should just start by looking at **Administration > Store > Configuration > Product pricing rules** to see what pricing rules are active and how they're manipulating prices.

Comment: I look at Product pricing rules, I find 3 rules: Unset the price of disabled products in the cart, Calculate taxes: VAT and Calculate taxes: Sales tax. I didn't set all those rules. I had installed the commerce installing all modules I didn't used the Kickstart.

Comment: If i disable the VAT rules the prices looks as is set. I don't understand the behavior, because the price includes a 10% VAT. But when the VAT rule is enabled the price is increased in a 25,82%. I checked that the tax rate is correctly set.